# Algorithm to find vertex subsets induced by connected components of a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, matrix, bipartite

Given a bipartite graph **G** = (**U**, **V**, **E**), I want to find all (maximal) subsets of **V** which are one "side" of a connected component of **G**.

For example, for the incidence matrix

```
    0 1 0 0 0 1
    1 0 0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 0 0 0
A = 0 0 0 0 1 0
    0 0 1 0 1 0
    0 1 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 1 0 0
```

where the row indices represent **U** and the column indices represent **V**, the output should be the sets {0, 1, 5}, {2, 4}, and {3}.

Is this equivalent to any standard problem? More to the point, is there an efficient solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "on one side" of a connected component? U is "one side" and V is "another side", so you want to know what's the connected component with the largest amount of elements in V. Is this correct?

Comment: How is this different from just finding the connected components of G and filtering out the nodes in U from these components?

Comment: @cyon, it's exactly that. I was just thinking there might be some way to take advantage of the bipartiteness of G.

Comment: Would you care to share where does this problem arise? I think the bipartiteness can be used to bound the size of the largest connected component from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to finding all the connected components of a graph, which is linear in the number of edges and vertices. The standard algorithm for this approach is to do a breadth or depth first search on every vertex.

I don't think there would be a complexity speed up by leveraging the bipartite nature of the graph, except for reducing the constants associated with this algorithm.